# CSS Line-height margin issues

Tags: html, margins, css

Quick question.

Does anyone know for a work-arround or fix for my problem:
[image]

The issue is that because of the line-height on the paragraph the start and bottom of the paragraph have some white space. In the example given above it's about 4px. But I do not want to edit my margins on other elements. For example, 40px margin would be 36px.

So does anyone know a good workarround for this?
I did find the css pseudoelement first-line: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoelement-firstline

Comment: Can I ask why you actually want to do this?

Comment: I don't want it and normally wouldn't because I believe such things are by design and one should not try to work-arround it. However some clients or projects are very strict when it comes do design.. I never came across this either but i have to make this design pixel-perfect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would approach this problem differently thank looking for a last line pseudo element.

If you are going to have some more content after the paragraph you can style this to move upwards closer to the last line of text.

For an idea of what i mean please see here -> http://jsfiddle.net/Z9LG9/1/

In response to your comment saying "keeping your style sheets as clean as possible" should you not be looking at creating a functional style sheet over a nice looking one? You can always clean up the style sheet after the build phase.

You are going to need to use negative margin for this. There is no way around it that will be cross browser capable.

Comment: The thing is I am trying to follow a grid system. And there you have margins like 40px 80px etc.. And I wouldn't want to edit these. I guess I will go with negative margins on paragraphs didn't think of that. With clean stylesheets I acctually meant the use of rounded figures.

Comment: Ah ok i get you, you can use negative margin on your paragraphs as well, just be careful not to select them all :) Good luck!